# Transfer form elements between tabs on scope change in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, oop

My problem is quite simple: I need to transfer form elements from one tab to another.

Say I've ten tabs and each tab has it's own set of text edits.

Is it possible to create just one set of text edits and transfer it from one tab to another,changing functionality behind it, but without changing the forms layout?

Currently I've "solved" that problem just by populating copy of text edit's for each tab but common sense tells me that there's a simpler way to achieve that in Qt.

I'm using Qt 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using a single [`QTabBar`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html). A `QTabBar`, as its name suggests, only displays a narrow bar with multiple tabs within.

[image]

You can put a frame below that tab bar and listen for tab change signal which is emitted by the `QTabBar`. In this way, the frame below is the same for all tabs, so you can change underlying logic for each tab.